# Xcode 10 simulator crashes

Tags: ios, ios-simulator, xcode10

Xcode 10 simulators crash even after the build is successful.
The following message appears on the screen :

**libMobileGestalt MobileGestalt.c:890: MGIsDeviceOneOfType is not supported on this platform.**

Comment: Are u parsing data from API?

Comment: No. I just created a single view app and ran the simulator. There is no parsing.

Comment: Can you file a bug report at https://bugreport.apple.com? Please leave the relevant simulator running, then run `xcrun simctl diagnose` from Terminal and attach the resulting file. It would also help if you could attach the `.crash` file from the crash.

Comment: Thanks for the details. The report has been sent to apple.

Answer (score 1):

Built to XS Max in the Simulator and the error will disappear.

Comment: Unfortunately, none of the simulators is working. Tried XS Max, XS but still, it crashes.

Getting the following : 

Exception Type:        EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGSEGV)
Exception Codes:       KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0x0000000000000000
Exception Note:        EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY

Is this error message of any help?